# Turn off shadow for DefaultItemizedOverlay

Tags: android, mapquest

I'm working with the MapQuest Android API and I'm using a [DefaultItemizedOverlay](https://developer.mapquest.com/content/mobile/android/documentation/api/index.html?com/mapquest/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html) to show a marker ([OverlayItem](https://developer.mapquest.com/content/mobile/android/documentation/api/index.html?com/mapquest/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html)). Unfortunately the marker is drawn on with a shadow... how can I remove this shadow or stop it from being drawn?

[image]

I know I could create a custom class and override the `draw` method from `Overlay` but I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION**

In the end, I had to create my own custom overlay and override the `draw` method:

```
@Override
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
    return super.draw(canvas, mapView, false, when);
}
```

Not the solution I wanted but the one I needed right now.